NgRx Store cant bind to the Angular17 App- state doesnt exists
I have a store with actions

import { createAction } from '@ngrx/store';

export const getPatientData = createAction('[Patient] Get Patient Data');
export const resetPatientData = createAction('[Patient] Reset Patient Data');

and reducer:
import { createReducer, createSelector, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { resetPatientData } from './patients.actions';

export interface Patient {
  age: number;
  name: string;
  last_name: string;
}

export interface PatientState {
  patient: Patient;
}

export const initialPatientState: PatientState = {
  patient: {
    age: 0,
    name: 'Adam',
    last_name: 'Smith',
  },
};

// selectors
export const selectPatient = (state: PatientState) => state.patient;
export const selectPatientData = createSelector(
  selectPatient,
  (patient: Patient) => patient,
);

export const patientReducer = createReducer(
  initialPatientState, // Initial state
  on(resetPatientData, () => initialPatientState), // Reset state to initial state on reset action
);


then i want to use it in my component:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-patients-data',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NgIconComponent,
    OverviewNavComponent,
    RouterLink,
    NgrxFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './patients-data.component.html',
  styleUrl: './patients-data.component.css',
  viewProviders: [
    provideIcons({
      bootstrapArrowRightCircleFill,
      bootstrapArrowLeftCircleFill,
    }),
  ],
})
export class PatientsDataComponent {
  patientData$: Observable<Patient>;

  constructor(private patientStore: Store<PatientState>) {
    this.patientData$ = this.patientStore.select(selectPatient);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.patientStore.dispatch(resetPatientData());
  }
}


and theres no data.
i check like:
<h1>Patients data</h1>
<div *ngIf="patientData$ | async as patient">
  <p>Patients data are</p>
  <p>Name: {{ patient.name }}</p>
  <p>Last Name: {{ patient.last_name }}</p>
  <p>Age: {{ patient.age }}</p>
</div>


heres package.json

{
  "name": "pharma-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:PharmaUI": "node dist/pharma-ui/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.2.0",
    "@ng-icons/bootstrap-icons": "^28.1.0",
    "@ng-icons/core": "^28.1.0",
    "@ng-icons/heroicons": "^28.1.0",
    "@ng-icons/tabler-icons": "^29.5.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^17.2.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "ngrx-forms": "^8.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.18.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.12.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.39",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.4",
    "typescript": "~5.3.2"
  }
}


I cant access any data. The ngOnInit method doesnt have any effect and, according to the dev tools, it isnt invoked. The code editor doesnt return any errors.
I installed redux dev tools, and it doesnt recognize any state, like my store didnt exist.
Why i can use the store? Why browser extension doesnt see the state? How to fix it?

How have you linked the reducer to the state? do you mind sharing the "StoreModule.forRoot" or "StoreModule.forFeature" statement?

In your component try to inject the store private store = inject(Store);   patient$: Observable<Patient>;
